# Regular expression for starting sequence

Tags: java, regex

```
package xmlchars;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

public static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "(?i)^[^a-z_]|[^a-z0-9-_.]";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = "#1998St #";  
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS);      
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(name).replaceAll(""));//gives wrong output 1998St            
}

}
```

Basically what i'm trying to achieve is

1. String to start only with a-z and _
2. String to contain a-z 0-9 _ - . after the start
3. Case insensitive for the whole string

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
... SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]+$";
```

and define the pattern by saying:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Then how do i replace all with the above :)

Comment: What is the "wrong output" you are getting? What do you expect to get?

Comment: @user2969818 You simply mentioned how the pattern should be.  It's touch to figure what else do you want.  Could you be more clear.

Comment: I want the string to start only with a-z and _

Comment: @user2969818 The above mentioned pattern would satisfy that.

Comment: Want to remove all, from the start of string which dont fall under a-z and _

Comment: How to do i remove everything that does not satisfy the above regex :)

Comment: @user2969818 `replaceAll` replaces everything which *does* satisfy the regular expression, not everything which *does not* satisfy it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to crack the regex. Simple change to the existing.

```
 "^[^a-z_]*|[^a-z_0-9-._]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, with the working proof.

```
package xmlchars;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

public static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "^[^a-z_]*|[^a-z_0-9-._]";  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = " # !`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[];:',<>/?19.- 98Cc#19 #/9_-8-.";      
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);        
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(name).replaceAll(""));   // output _19.-98Cc199_-8-.
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are trying to identify anything in the `String` that doesn't match the pattern. What you have looks almost correct. It looks like your regex might work like this:

```
 "(?i)^([^a-z_]|[^a-z0-9-_.])"
```

That would only match whenever one of those two groups appear at the **start** of the `String`. Instead, try this:

```
"(?i)(^[^a-z_])|[^a-z0-9-_.]"
```

To shorten it even further, you could use the [predefined character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) `\\W` which is the same as `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]`. With that, you wouldn't even need the case-insensitivity.

```
"(^\\W)|[\\W-.]"
```

---

Given a `String` called `str`, `str.replaceAll("(^\\W)|[\\W-.]","");` will remove all invalid characters.

---

Test for your string:

```
class RegexTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String str = "#1998St #";
        str = str.replaceAll("(^\\W)|[\\W-.]","");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1998St